# WebcamException error when using webcam-capture

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, webcam-capture

I am trying to use the webcam-capture Java library, but I keep getting an WebcamException error.

This is what I have in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
```

The sample code I am running

```
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File("file_path"));
```

The error message:

```
[main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture driver will be used
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:124)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getWebcams(Webcam.java:893)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:956)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:933)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:911)
    at com.datacollection.Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:116)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:72)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:140)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$GetDevicesTask.getDevices(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:79)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver.getDevices(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:124)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:36)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:26)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.natives.OpenIMAJGrabber.getVideoDevices()Lorg/bridj/Pointer;
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.natives.OpenIMAJGrabber.getVideoDevices(Native Method)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$GetDevicesTask.handle(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:93)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:81)
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why are you using alpha version instead of a stable version like 1.7.36? It would be helpful to others if you post error log, pom file and logback configurations

Comment: Thanks, I added more info as well as used the stable version. Now have a different error message

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j-simple is in scope “test” meaning it is available to test classes only.

Remove that line and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me go further, but now i have a new error

Comment: Don’t change your questions into something completely different as it makes answers useless to others. Open a new question instead, and close the old one.